# Test production Rails server boot with Github actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github-actions

I use Github Action to run RSpec test. I would be sure that the Rails server can successfully run in production mode. By successfully, I mean this command run for a few seconds without raising exceptions.

```
bundle exec rails s -e production
```

If we add this step to the action workflow, we can't stop the server if successful because it runs forever.

```
  - name: RSpec
    run: |
      bundle exec rspec ./spec
  - name: Boot Rails server
    run: bundle exec rails s -e production
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to write a script and put it in `bin/test_boot`:

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

pid = Process.spawn("bundle exec rails s -e production") # run the server and get its PID
sleep 5 # time in seconds you need to ensure the server boots without errors
Process.kill("INT", pid) # send ^C, gracefully terminate the server

_, status = Process.wait2(pid) # wait for the server termination and get its exit code
exit status.exitstatus # exit from the script with the same code as the server
```

And update the CI config file to:

```yaml
  - name: Boot Rails server
    run: bin/test_boot
```

CI pipeline decides whether it failed or not by the exit code of each step, and the `Boot Rails server` step exits with the same code as the server.

Comment: Good idea. I've tried but returned
Run bin/test_boot
/home/runner/work/_temp/4949d857-4e14-4318-b8b8-f92bf21dc65e.sh: line 1: bin/test_boot: Permission denied
Error: Process completed with exit code 126.

Comment: @sparkle have you executed `chmod +x bin/test_boot` before committing this file? Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: @sparkle could you please run this script locally before sending it to GitHub to ensure you have correct setup?

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with the selected solution. Since we are using puma the PID of puma wasn't matching the one from calling `bundle exec`

And since it runs `detached` can't use wait2 in non-child processes.

This is what I ended up doing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

pid = Process.spawn("RAILS_ENV=staging bundle exec rails s -e staging") # run the ser

puts "Started. Parent PID #{pid}"

sleep 10 # time in seconds you need to ensure the server boots without errors

puma_pid = `pgrep -f puma`.to_i

if puma_pid == 0
  puts "Puma crashed!"
  exit 1
end

puts "Puma PID: #{puma_pid}"

Process.kill("INT", puma_pid) # send ^C, gracefully terminate the server

sleep 2

exit 0
```